# Empty results when using sampleRegions

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I have a list of multiple raster images, from which I want to select different bands from each image. Then I also have a list of coordinates, and I want to get the results for all coordinates across all bands. So if I have 10 images and 100 coordinates, I should get 100 results.

The problem is, some of the rasters have gaps in them, so some might not return any data for some coordinates. This is the code I am using:

```py
geometries = [ee.Geometry.Point([longitude, latitude]) for longitude, latitude in coordinates]
images = [ee.ImageCollection(collection).select(band_name) for collection, band_name in collections]
bands = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(images).toBands()
bands.sampleRegions(collection=ee.FeatureCollection(geometries), scale=30)
```

Strangely, if one of the bands has no data, then the whole thing returns an empty `features` list. How to handle this so that I can get all values where there is data?

Comment: All of the `sample*` functions drop partially masked pixels.  `unmask` the input images so the masked values are replaced with something else if you want those locations.

Comment: But `unmask` only works if using a value that already exists in the image, right? so say in my image I've got values from 0 to 100 for examples, I dont want the coordinates with missing values to return `0`, I want to know they are missing.

Comment: Or maybe there would be a "null" image that could be used?